# Need to take Jenkins jobs backup last 15 days using shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to Jenkins server,
Take the back up of Jenkins jobs and plugins and delete the same which is older than 15days.. with shell script

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is present in your Jenkins home folder. If you want to take a backup of your job configuration, you can copy the config.xml file found inside the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job_name>` directory. The directory will also have a list of builds which will contain the logs of these builds, so you can take a backup of this as well if necessary. As for the plugins, you can find them in the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` folder. The `.jpi` and `.hpi` files are the plugin files.

As for deleting files older that 15 days, [this article](https://computingforgeeks.com/find-delete-files-older-than-n-days-linux/) gives a pretty comprehensive method for doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your support... Actually we need take backup with shell script, not manually

Comment: You can automate the above steps with a shell scripts using copy and delete commands.